# Does "felt" belong to "excluded" in this context?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> It declared that it felt no longer represented in the Federal
> Council, excluded the two serving federal councillors elected as SVP
> members from its parliamentary group and declared ‘fundamental
> opposition’ to the government.\
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Wolf linder*

Does this sentence go like:

1. "It declared that it felt no longer represented and felt excluded"
   or
2. "It declared that it felt no longer represented and it excluded two councilors"
   ?

Comment: No 2 is correct. The comma after Council breaks up the sentence. Another option would have been to write: **.....Federal Council. (It) excluded....** The second **it** is elided as being understood.

Comment: Thank you for explanation.